# Use text input as variable for getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I work as an ambulance officer for a community that has random house numbers that don't conform to any recognizable pattern. It can take valuable time to scan a map for an unfamiliar house number. I have made an SVG map of the houses and house numbers and I would like to highlight the appropriate house by entering the house number in a text field to use as a variable in a getElementById JS function, to change the SVG 'fill' property for that element, to highlight the right house. My knowledge of JS is rudimentary, and I have not found any examples of how to achieve this on my searches. My example below is a complete kludge, but illustrates what I am trying to do, except with a text input instead of a button for every house.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test SVG</title>
    <style>

        .default {
            fill: #008000;
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-width: 3px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .selected {
            fill: #ff0000;
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-width: 3px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        text {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        div {
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <svg width="500" height="500">
        
        <g>
            <circle class="default" id="01" cx="380" cy="400" r="40" />
            <text x="373" y="408">1</text>
        </g>
        
        <g>
            <circle class="default" id="02" cx="380" cy="60" r="40" />
            <text x="373" y="68">2</text>
        </g>

        <g>
            <circle class="default" id="03" cx="80" cy="240" r="40" />
            <text x="74" y="248">3</text>
        </g>

        <g>
            <circle class="default" id="04" cx="430" cy="210" r="40" />
            <text x="423" y="218">4</text>
        </g>

        <g>
            <circle class="default" id="05" cx="110" cy="60" r="40" />
            <text x="103" y="68">5</text>
        </g>

        <g>
            <circle class="default" id="06" cx="230" cy="130" r="40" />
            <text x="224" y="138">6</text>
        </g>

        <g>
            <circle class="default" id="07" cx="130" cy="370" r="40" />
            <text x="124" y="378">7</text>
        </g>

        <g>
            <circle class="default" id="08" cx="280" cy="280" r="40" />
            <text x="273" y="288">8</text>
        </g>

    </svg>

    <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="select01()">House 1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="select02()">House 2</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="select03()">House 3</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="select04()">House 4</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="select05()">House 5</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="select06()">House 6</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="select07()">House 7</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="select08()">House 8</button>    
    </div>

    <script>
        function select01() {
            const element = document.getElementById("01");
            element.classList.toggle("selected")
        }
        function select02() {
            const element = document.getElementById("02");
            element.classList.toggle("selected")
        }
        function select03() {
            const element = document.getElementById("03");
            element.classList.toggle("selected")
        }
        function select04() {
            const element = document.getElementById("04");
            element.classList.toggle("selected")
        }
        function select05() {
            const element = document.getElementById("05");
            element.classList.toggle("selected")
        }
        function select06() {
            const element = document.getElementById("06");
            element.classList.toggle("selected")
        }
        function select07() {
            const element = document.getElementById("07");
            element.classList.toggle("selected")
        }
        function select08() {
            const element = document.getElementById("08");
            element.classList.toggle("selected")
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tat more JavaScript knowledge will save you time.

You can create your own `<svg-house-map>` Native JavaScript *Web Component* (JSWC)

```
<svg-house-map>
  <svg>
    <house>1a,30,20</house> 
    <house>2,100,15</house>  
    <house>32,150,25</house>
  </svg>
</svg-house-map>
```

It will read all defined `<house>NR,CX,CY></house>` elements and *inserts* them into the `<svg>`

This gives you full control on how houses are displayed; you only have to change the HTML *once* inside the Web Component *definition*

To selected **and** unselected houses it is easier to alter/swap your `<input>` logic to:

- ***Every house listens** to the input,

  and checks if `input.value` **matches to its own house number***

All code required:

```html
<svg-house-map>
  <input type="text" placeholder="house number?"><br>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 0 0" style="background:pink">
    <style>.selected { fill: green }</style>
    <house>1a,30,20</house> <house>2,100,15</house>  <house>32,150,25</house>
    <house>11,25,55</house> <house>22a,80,50</house> <house>222b,180,46</house>
  </svg>
</svg-house-map>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-house-map", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till innerHTML <svg> is parsed
        let vbx = [], vby = []; // calc viewBox dimensions with padding
        let svg    = this.querySelector("svg");
        Array.from(  svg.querySelectorAll("house")  ).forEach(house => {
          let [nr, cx, cy, r=10, pad=5 ] = house.innerHTML.split(",");
          vbx.push(Number(cx) + r + pad); vby.push(Number(cy) + r + pad);
          house.innerHTML = `<circle cx="${cx}" cy="${cy}" r="${r}"
                              fill="lightgrey" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>` +
            // align the text label:
            `<path id="NR${nr}" d="M${cx-r} ${cy}h${r*2}" stroke="yellow"/>` +
            `<text><textPath href="#NR${nr}" startoffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"
                    fill="darkred" font-size="${r*.9}px">${nr}</textPath></text>`; 
          // now in the DOM, then grab this! <circle> reference:
          let circle = house.querySelector("circle");
          this.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", (evt) => {
               let match = evt.target.value && nr.includes(evt.target.value);
               circle.classList.toggle("selected", match );
          });
          house.replaceWith(...house.children); // replace <house> with created SVG tags
        })// Array.from
        svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + Math.max(...vbx) + " " + Math.max(...vby));
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Danny, that is a complex, but **very** elegant solution. I love the fact that it is easily scalable. It's going to make a real difference to our response time. I _really_ appreciate the effort, mate.