SVG - Putting Text on Top of SVG Path
I am hoping someone can help me figure out how to put a county name on top of a specifc county in this HTML code.
HTML
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 499 568" version="1.1" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round;">
  <g id="Chippewa" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-48.28,-13.5967)" >    <a href="https://www.google.com/" > 
    <path d="M114.497,420.065L118.322,420.202L119.579,420.241L119.607,420.257L126.613,420.447L131.781,420.598L131.889,420.612L134.899,420.704L136.236,420.744L139.008,420.814L140.394,420.852L143.144,420.922L150.042,421.066L151.001,421.09L151.058,421.09L151.412,421.088L151.423,421.085L151.434,421.09L159.714,421.176L166.645,421.344L166.766,421.364L167.78,421.392L168.038,421.385L168.019,422.071L167.958,424.162L167.91,426.23L167.838,429.717L167.724,433.422L167.714,433.736L167.676,434.59L167.567,438.051L167.457,442.226L167.435,443.604L167.431,443.853L167.425,444.172L167.399,445.557L167.384,446.378L159.723,446.229L159.079,446.219L157.492,446.19L154.885,446.145L151.437,446.085L151.43,446.174L151.368,448.528L151.315,449.255L151.308,449.531L151.308,449.55L151.222,454.414L151.224,454.423L151.216,454.776L151.141,454.774L151.127,455.095L151.208,455.1L151.156,457.996L151.133,459.309L150.855,459.472L150.643,459.403L150.548,459.271L150.57,459.103L150.53,458.719L150.566,458.376L150.698,458.277L150.695,458.181L150.532,458.006L150.321,457.637L150.289,457.62L150.149,457.591L150.028,457.548L149.939,457.5L149.903,457.471L149.675,457.32L149.542,457.368L149.382,457.622L149.445,457.917L149.333,458.03L149.199,458.037L148.93,457.908L148.915,457.788L148.973,457.502L148.898,457.416L148.746,457.421L148.405,457.613L148.269,457.615L148.043,457.502L147.951,457.389L147.927,457.125L148.012,457.097L148.201,457.14L148.448,457.075L148.484,456.943L148.309,456.717L148.254,456.398L148.295,456.319L148.588,456.262L149.146,456.307L149.419,456.252L149.61,456.134L149.948,456.072L150.146,455.998L150.211,455.81L149.968,455.527L149.786,455.266L149.541,455.191L149.371,455.1L149.228,454.946L148.995,454.769L148.747,454.531L148.461,454.495L148.14,454.469L147.38,454.438L147.005,454.327L146.992,454.311L147.082,454.147L147.334,454.02L147.665,453.583L147.688,453.502L147.687,453.336L147.617,453.233L147.095,452.811L146.971,452.792L146.557,452.552L146.214,452.499L146.022,452.422L145.762,452.125L145.57,451.858L145.557,451.64L145.661,451.436L145.526,451.241L145.432,451.04L145.152,450.759L144.922,450.891L144.763,450.869L144.494,450.728L144.172,450.673L143.326,450.442L143.315,450.318L143.6,449.998L143.586,449.852L143.307,449.696L143.055,449.77L142.762,449.847L142.548,449.842L142.335,449.696L142.266,449.54L142.261,449.346L142.375,449.046L142.4,448.844L142.295,448.515L141.991,448.081L141.786,448.038L141.596,447.939L141.363,447.479L141.352,447.318L141.201,447.068L141.096,447.126L141.075,447.342L140.893,447.498L140.624,447.404L140.397,447.124L140.259,446.915L139.757,446.373L139.733,446.291L139.824,446.221L140.071,446.233L140.164,446.147L140.183,446.022L140.054,445.78L139.915,445.78L139.685,445.957L139.59,445.96L139.392,445.833L139.312,445.729L139.104,445.453L138.996,445.391L138.53,445.209L138.44,445.144L138.463,445.041L138.615,444.945L138.656,444.678L138.592,444.482L138.37,444.326L138.135,444.047L137.951,443.937L137.829,443.937L137.812,444.054L137.938,444.054L138.057,444.172L137.702,444.527L137.56,444.638L137.335,444.638L136.958,444.448L136.79,444.477L136.373,444.458L136.048,444.477L135.894,444.29L135.464,444.239L135.265,444.1L135.115,443.906L135.118,443.826L135.343,443.793L135.441,443.714L135.312,443.287L135.293,442.857L135.432,442.749L135.103,442.298L134.971,442.166L134.912,441.967L134.712,441.746L134.546,441.676L134.485,441.434L134.284,441.321L134.113,441.211L133.753,441.067L133.739,440.983L133.977,440.985L133.84,440.525L133.741,440.455L133.623,440.469L133.613,440.789L133.441,440.858L133.452,440.745L133.327,440.537L133.013,440.292L132.858,440.246L132.864,440.34L133.044,440.618L132.962,440.755L132.698,440.714L132.305,440.7L132.344,440.611L132.667,440.633L132.612,440.486L132.317,440.227L132.085,440.121L132.027,440.544L131.835,440.676L131.561,440.63L131.447,440.364L131.38,440.285L131.049,440.107L130.934,440.001L130.873,440.177L130.685,439.949L130.589,439.989L130.654,440.225L130.472,440.162L130.256,440.138L129.774,439.968L129.714,439.925L129.701,439.692L129.588,439.639L129.386,439.622L129.318,439.545L129.352,439.423L129.558,439.416L129.476,439.171L129.306,438.907L129.302,438.828L129.272,438.739L129.085,438.782L128.953,438.751L128.792,438.804L128.62,438.713L128.481,438.391L128.587,438.367L128.51,438.257L128.685,438.053L128.478,438.072L128.434,437.959L128.541,437.837L128.463,437.614L128.515,437.395L128.435,437.153L128.484,437.103L128.381,436.793L128.524,436.793L128.438,436.296L128.386,436.186L128.186,436.064L128.041,436.097L128.023,435.989L128.274,435.994L128.395,435.819L128.185,435.74L128.022,435.927L127.871,435.819L127.812,435.701L128.067,435.516L127.854,435.617L127.698,435.435L127.879,435.217L127.774,435.19L127.643,435.399L127.511,435.344L127.499,435.137L127.284,435.077L127.067,434.794L126.423,434.501L126.205,434.35L126.179,434.338L126.028,434.249L126.07,434.199L125.895,433.796L125.675,433.714L125.635,433.46L125.702,433.323L125.566,433.098L125.509,432.735L125.466,432.62L125.346,432.584L125.387,432.706L125.314,432.752L125.204,432.596L125.138,432.62L125.115,432.834L125.024,432.75L124.758,432.673L124.707,432.51L124.758,432.445L124.883,432.503L124.95,432.452L124.76,432.217L124.646,432.275L124.534,432.251L124.482,432.123L124.517,431.972L124.673,431.811L124.661,431.754L124.436,431.763L124.272,431.595L124.12,431.562L123.804,431.418L119.392,426.71L119.315,426.578L118.165,425.407L117.351,424.116L117.179,424.044L116.944,424.029L116.798,423.895L116.818,423.794L116.705,423.597L116.756,423.516L116.895,423.604L116.943,423.492L116.906,423.285L116.64,423.192L116.67,422.993L116.429,422.863L116.142,422.875L116.059,422.839L115.972,422.657L115.91,422.359L115.748,422.131L115.561,421.99L115.509,421.735L115.391,421.514L115.224,421.615L115.179,421.517L115.197,421.334L115.109,421.289L115.025,421.087L115.036,420.986L114.915,420.79L114.74,420.638L114.481,420.262L114.497,420.065"  /></a> 

</a><text>dsaasd</text>
  </g>
 
  <g id="Layer1">
  </g>
</svg>

CSS
svg {
  fill         : rgb(0, 28, 101);
  stroke       : black;
  stroke-width : 1px;
  }
svg g:hover {
  fill         : white;
  }
text {
  display           : block;
  color             : black;
  font-size         = "100px";
  font-family       = "Ewert";
  text-align        : center;
  text-anchor       = "middle";
  dominant-baseline = "middle";
  dy                = ".3em";
  dx                = "-10";
  }

I just can not get the text to display over top of the specific county it is attached to. What am I missing?

Like this?. Try to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, please.

SVG text elements can't automatically be aligned to a parent element (like in HTML). So you need to calculate a suitable center point to align the text element, e.g via getBBox(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992691/how-to-place-text-in-the-center-of-an-svg-path.

It is a matter of grabbing the object you want a  for, calculate a  over it, then display the label in the center; kinda like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77252363/use-text-input-as-variable-for-getelementbyid/77253352#77253352 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263255/how-to-make-an-svg-interactive-to-gather-comments-annotations-on-depicted-elemen/66385760#66385760
